# How to pass API data to another component while we using route?

Tags: reactjs

I my react app i am getting error when i try to pass the data from 1 component to another via route . If i pass the data by props without route my data is showing in output.my server was working perfectly .

```
App.js
function App() {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = (apiUrl, setData) => {
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((Data) => {
        setData(Data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error:", err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData("http://localhost:3004/dresses", setAllData);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<All />} allData={allData} />
          <Route path="mens" element={<Mens />} />
          <Route path="women" element={<Women />} />
          <Route path="kids" element={<Kids />} />{" "}
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
All.js
function All({ allData }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card-holder">
        <div className="card">
          {allData.map((allData) => (
            <ShopingCard
              key={allData.id}
              image={allData.image}
              name={allData.name}
              price={allData.price}
              description={allData.description}
              category={allData.category}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default All;
```

My data form App.js will not show in All.js its become undefined

Comment: ``{<All allData={allData} />}`` instead of ``{<All />} allData={allData}`` !

Comment: thx buddy this works perfectly . i am an newbie thats why am asking for it .

Answer (score 0):

to pass data on routing you can use in-built functions provided by `"react-router-dom"` ,i.e., `useNavigateHook`.

You can refer to the official documentation of [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate).
[image]

And also to this [article](https://dev.to/thatfemicode/passing-data-states-through-react-router-8dh)

Hope this helps :)